# AppEngine Remote API returning "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found Too many auth attempts."

Tags: google-app-engine

I am switching my project to OAuth 2.0 since ClientLogin is going away and am running into this when using scripts invoking the remote API.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this to help others who might be migrating from ClientLogin to the OAuth based API. In my case I was using remote API with a custom mapping in app.yaml. I had to remove one line and then the error went away:

```
- url: /(?:[^/]*)/remote_api
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
  login: admin    <----- remove this line
  secure: always
```

Comment: Is there a JAVA  equivalent for this? I am trying to migrate from clientlogin to OAuth but It keeps giving me 302 error

Comment: @ManishaAwasthi If you are hitting the same issue java has an equivalent XML file called appengine-web.xml that you need to check

Comment: official bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12962